# Set paper size of thermal printer when printing from Android device

Tags: android, thermal-printer

I am printing invoice from android tablets to ethernet thermal printer connected on the same network.

Everything works fine when using below code.

```
  MyHsWifiPrintDriver hsWifiPrintDriver = MyHsWifiPrintDriver.getInstance();
    boolean connection = hsWifiPrintDriver.WIFISocket(printeraddress, 9100);

    if(connection==false)
    {
        insert(printeraddress,arr,ordertype,kitchenname,section,"Table - "+texttablenumber.getText().toString()
                ,invno,date,time,uname,textwaiter.getText().toString());
    }

    else {

        try {
            //setting font size

            hsWifiPrintDriver.WIFI_Write(new byte[]{(byte) 29, (byte) 33, 16});
            hsWifiPrintDriver.WIFI_Write(new byte[]{(byte) 27, (byte) 97, 1});


            hsWifiPrintDriver.WIFI_Write("\n-----------------------------------------".getBytes("UTF-8"));

            hsWifiPrintDriver.WIFI_Write(("\n" + ordertype).getBytes("UTF-8"));


            hsWifiPrintDriver.WIFI_Write("\n-----------------------------------------".getBytes("UTF-8"));
            hsWifiPrintDriver.WIFI_Write(("\n" + kitchenname).getBytes("UTF-8"));


            hsWifiPrintDriver.WIFI_Write("\n-----------------------------------------".getBytes("UTF-8"));
            hsWifiPrintDriver.WIFI_Write(("\n" + section).getBytes("UTF-8"));


            hsWifiPrintDriver.WIFI_Write("\n-----------------------------------------".getBytes("UTF-8"));
            hsWifiPrintDriver.WIFI_Write(("\nTABLE - " + texttablenumber.getText().toString()).getBytes("UTF-8"));

            hsWifiPrintDriver.WIFI_Write("\n-----------------------------------------".getBytes("UTF-8"));

            hsWifiPrintDriver.WIFI_Write(new byte[]{(byte) 27, (byte) 97, 0});
            hsWifiPrintDriver.WIFI_Write(("\nBill No:" + invno).getBytes("UTF-8"));

            hsWifiPrintDriver.WIFI_Write(("\nDate" + datenew).getBytes("UTF-8"));

            hsWifiPrintDriver.WIFI_Write(("\n" + timenew).getBytes("UTF-8"));

            hsWifiPrintDriver.WIFI_Write(("\nUser:" + uname).getBytes("UTF-8"));

            hsWifiPrintDriver.WIFI_Write(new byte[]{(byte) 10});
            hsWifiPrintDriver.WIFI_Write(new byte[]{(byte) 27, (byte) 105});

            hsWifiPrintDriver.stop();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

My problem is paper size of printer changing into large size when i switch off the printer and on it.So some contents are missing.After some seconds (less than one minute) it will back to normal.

but its working fine when taking print out from windows PC.

This problem started after printer manufacturer updated the printer for supporting Arabic..May be manufacturer can set it..

My question is ,
**How can i set paper size programmatically before printing from android?**

its 80mm therml printer.

Printer manual is attached below..
[Click here to view printer manual](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7g1yxe8Al17NFZrMHFkbkY2TzQ)

Comment: That depends on the printer. Your best option is to contact the printer manufacturer.

Comment: printer manufacturer reply very late..if we can give solution in our way that will be best option na?  Sir,, is there any byte code somthing like this code 
  -    "hsWifiPrintDriver.WIFI_Write(new byte[]{(byte) 27, (byte) 97, 1}); " for setting printer size....this line is just to align characters in center

Comment: As I already said that depends on the printer. Maybe you find something in the printer manual.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7g1yxe8Al17NFZrMHFkbkY2TzQ

Comment: I couldnt find anything in this document .. i have checked enough ..any help will be appreciable